# AndroidStudio 2.2 build gradle error ( path to custom proguard file )

Tags: android, build.gradle, proguard, android-studio-2.2

previous installed `AndroidStuio` version was :`2.1.3` but after update to `2.2` and update gradle, building gradle has a problem Because of the proguard name.

Before, for release `.Apk` i use a custom proguard config with this way:

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('fileName.txt')
    }
}
```

but after update `AndroidStudio 2.1.3` to `2.2` this error occurs:

```
Error:(17, 0) User supplied default proguard base extension name is unsupported. 
Valid values are: [proguard-android.txt, proguard-android-optimize.txt]
Open File
```

**Notice That :** After update settings and config files imported from previous version And `SDK` folder path not chnage

---

**old way!**
Unfortunately and finally, I had to use old version of AndroidStudio(2.1.3) and
this work but not is solution for AndroidStudio 2.2

Comment: Try to change `minifyEnabled false` -> Clean project -> Rebuild project.

Let me know if this works out.

Comment: @SouravChandra , Clean + Invalidate Cache And Restart, but not work!

Comment: Can you try changing to `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('filename.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`

Comment: Also try `proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('fileName.txt')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**way 1 :**

After several tests I found that I should set complete path to `proguard file` like following config :

**in build.gradle(module:app) :**

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile ('FullPath/.../configFileName.txt')
    }
}
```

, and no need to using `getDefaultProguardFile` before path.

Too , you can paste your `config file` to  `...\appName\app` and chanage `proguardFile` to :

```
 proguardFile ('configFileName.txt')
```

Actually , default path is `.../appName/app` and if you put just `configFileName` , this will search file name in default project path.

in previous version I had't this problem and `default gradle path` was `...\SDK\tools\proguard`

---

update

**way 2 :** 
in below image and step 4 you can browse and select `ProguardFile` for `debug` or `release`

[image]

And in `build.gradle(module:app)` file , `ProguardFile` path will add automatically

Answer (score 1):

try changing like the below

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt') fileName.txt // or file('{path_to_file}/fileName.txt')
    }
}
```

guess it supports proguard-android.txt or proguard-android-optimize.txt for default proguard file as it stated in the message.

proguard-android.txt was located in ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard in my case.

I think android studio retrieve that file. or you may make proguard-android.txt in the project folder and add the path in getDefaultProguardFile parameter (I haven't tried it though).

After then you can add your additional proguard file by adding like the code above.